# spacy model does not recognize street names as entity

Tags: spacy

I have tried several models and the results are as follows

en_core_web_sm
10030 W. Olivia Terrace DATE

en_core_web_md
W. Olivia Terrace  FACT

en_core_web_lg
10030 CARDINAL
W. Olivia Terrace PERSON

how i train a model with an entity to recognize streets ?
Should I use regular expressions to identify these entities?

Answer (score 1):

The English models are not trained to recognize street names. You can find the list of pretrained NER labels from the [models page](https://spacy.io/models/en):

```
CARDINAL, DATE, EVENT, FAC, GPE, LANGUAGE, LAW, LOC, MONEY, NORP, ORDINAL, ORG, PERCENT, PERSON, PRODUCT, QUANTITY, TIME, WORK_OF_ART
```

To recognize a new type of entity, you can follow the documentation here: https://spacy.io/usage/training#example-new-entity-type. You'll have to create custom training data and update the model by calling `nlp.update` with the gold-standard annotations.

If your entities are very regular, it might be possible to just use a pattern-matching approach. In which case you can explore the docs here: https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching